# Graph theory -- the number of verticies of graph G

Tags: graph-theory

A connected planar graph G has 20 faces, and every vertex of G has degree exactly 4.

Find the number of vertices of G.

---

How should I start? I have tried to draw some diagrams, but they lead to nothing.

Comment: If it has $v$ vertices, how many edges does it have?

Comment: If a graph has v vertices, then it will have $v+f-2$ edges by Euler's theorem.

Comment: On the other hand, if every vertex has degree 4 then it will have..... edges?

Comment: $f+2$??? I am a bit confused.

Comment: $2v$. The number of edges is half the sum of degrees. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma

Comment: OHHHH THAT ONE... isn't it the one where a graph has degree $d$, then it has $\frac{dV}2$ edges?

Comment: How do I continue?

Comment: OP, you literally have 2 equations and 2 variables...

Comment: ...I only see one equation...
What's the second?

Comment: You have counted the edges in _two different ways_.

Comment: so it is e=2v and e=v+f-2? But that's 3 variables?

Comment: The value of $f$ is given in the problem statement.

Comment: I am dumb. So its e=2v and e=v+18 so v=18. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V,E,F$ be the numbers of vertices, edges, and faces of G, respectively. By Euler's theorem, we know that $$V-E+F=2.$$

We know $F=20$. Also, since every vertex has degree 4, we have $E=\frac{4V}2=2V$ and thus
$$V-2V+20=2.$$
Solving this equation yields $V=\boxed{18}$.